# how to change drracket splash screen to the valentine one

Tags: lisp, racket

I want to make the default splash screen for DrRacket the special one they use for valentine. One way to have it on your screen is to change the time on your computer to 14th of February. How can i put it as default splash screen without having to change the time?

Here you can find the special splash screen:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sj1RN.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/wXsDL.jpg

Answer (score 5):

Set the environment variable `PLTDREASTERSECONDS`.
Set it to a value that matches 14th of february.

An alternative is to open

https://github.com/racket/drracket/blob/master/drracket-test/tests/drracket/easter-egg.rkt

and play around with `start-up-on-day`.

Comment: How do i set the environment variable?

Comment: Depends on your OS. You'll need to look it up.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting [`the-bitmap-spec` here](https://github.com/racket/drracket/blob/master/drracket/drracket/private/drracket-normal.rkt#L210) to just `valentines-days-spec`.

Comment: The issue is that I cannot find the files mentioned in this thread. If i search for "drracket-normal.rkt" on my computer, it does not show up. I've also tried looking for that file, and other files mentioned in this thread by going in the "Racket" folder, but could not find them. Perhaps I need to reinstall DrRacket?

Comment: Is there a `share` folder in the place where you installed racket? For example (on my linux machine) I can find the file at `share/pkgs/drracket/drracket/private/drracket-normal.rkt`